WRF rain output time series ideas?
To obtain rain time series, I did RAINC + RAINCC for each time from my simulation. To have hourly data from simulation, I subtract RAINC and RAINCC from the subsequent time (rain time 2 - rain time 1 e.g) Does anyone knows a different approach?
